# How can I parse data in the form of nested curly braces { } with duplicated names?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse the following string

```
EOB {
   PROCEDURE { /* #1  */
      PROCEDURE_LINE="1"
      ELIGIBLE="002750"
      DEDUCTIBLE="00000"
   }
   PROCEDURE { /* #2  */
      PROCEDURE_LINE="2"
      ELIGIBLE="008725"
      DEDUCTIBLE="00000"
   }
   PROCEDURE { /* #3  */
      PROCEDURE_LINE="3"
      ELIGIBLE="010760"
      DEDUCTIBLE="00000"
   }
   PROCEDURE { /* #4  */
      PROCEDURE_LINE="4"
      ELIGIBLE="021720"
   }
   EMBEDDED_TRANSACTION {
      PROCEDURE { /* #1  */
         PROCEDURE_LINE="1"
         ELIGIBLE="002750"
         DEDUCTIBLE="00000"
      }
      PROCEDURE { /* #2  */
         PROCEDURE_LINE="2"
         ELIGIBLE="008725"
         DEDUCTIBLE="00000"
      }
      PROCEDURE { /* #3  */
         PROCEDURE_LINE="3"
         ELIGIBLE="010760"
         DEDUCTIBLE="00000"
      }
      PROCEDURE { /* #4  */
         PROCEDURE_LINE="4"
         ELIGIBLE="021720"
         DEDUCTIBLE="00000"
      }
   }
}
```

Desired output (Javascript object)

```
{
    EOB: {
        PROCEDURE: [
            {
                PROCEDURE_LINE="1",
                ELIGIBLE="002750",
                DEDUCTIBLE="00000"
            } ... (other procedures)
        ],
        EMBEDDED_TRANSACTION: [
            {
                PROCEDURE_LINE="1",
                ELIGIBLE="002750",
                DEDUCTIBLE="00000"
            } ,,, (other procedures)
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is what I have tried

```js
let data = `EOB {
   PROCEDURE { /* #1  */
  PROCEDURE_LINE="1"
  ELIGIBLE="002750"
  DEDUCTIBLE="00000"
   }
   PROCEDURE { /* #2  */
  PROCEDURE_LINE="2"
  ELIGIBLE="008725"
  DEDUCTIBLE="00000"
   }
   PROCEDURE { /* #3  */
  PROCEDURE_LINE="3"
  ELIGIBLE="010760"
  DEDUCTIBLE="00000"
   }
   PROCEDURE { /* #4  */
  PROCEDURE_LINE="4"
  ELIGIBLE="021720"
   }
   EMBEDDED_TRANSACTION {
  PROCEDURE { /* #1  */
     PROCEDURE_LINE="1"
     ELIGIBLE="002750"
     DEDUCTIBLE="00000"
  }
  PROCEDURE { /* #2  */
     PROCEDURE_LINE="2"
     ELIGIBLE="008725"
     DEDUCTIBLE="00000"
  }
  PROCEDURE { /* #3  */
     PROCEDURE_LINE="3"
     ELIGIBLE="010760"
     DEDUCTIBLE="00000"
  }
  PROCEDURE { /* #4  */
     PROCEDURE_LINE="4"
     ELIGIBLE="021720"
     DEDUCTIBLE="00000"
  }
   }
}`

  let output =  data.replace(/\/\*.+/g, '')
                    .replace(/(.*)(\{)/g, '[$1]\n')
                    .replace(/'*.}/, '')
                    .replace(/}/g, '')
                    .replace(/^\s*\n/gm, "")
                    .replace(/.*?(?==)/g, s => s.toLowerCase())
                    .replace(/\s+"/g, '"');

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Is this related to JSON? If yes then please tag accordingly and use a JSON parser instead of regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to design your own parser.  It is like partial JSON, yet with XML aspects (duplicated names).  Sort of like JSONXML-ISH. ;) Anyhow, I took up the challenge and came up with something to get you started (as I'm only going by the data you posted). You can change this to suit your own needs:

```
function parse(data) {
  var parts = data.match(/\/\*.*?\*\/|{|}|=|".*?"|[a-zA-Z_]+/g); // get only the data parts we want
  var root = {}, o = root, stack = [], name, prop;
  function readValue(s) { return +s || (s[0]=='"' ? s.substring(1, s.length-1) : s); } // read as number, string, or other
  parts.forEach((v, i) => {
     if (!v) return; // skip whitespace
     else if (v.substr(0,2) == '/*') return; // skip comment blocks
     else if (v == '{' && name) { 
        stack.push(o); // get ready to move up a level
        // ... first check of there is already a property here and convert it to an array if so ...
        if (!(name in o)) 
           o = o[name] = {}; // first time we assume no array
        else { // (else there are duplicates with the same name; add as an array instead)
           if (!o[name].length) o[name] = [o[name]]; // if not already an array convert it into one first
           o[name].push(o = {}); // add new object (o is the current object being updated)
        }
        name = ''; // reset
     }
     else if (v == '}') o = stack.pop(); // pop prevfious object from stack
     else if (v == '=') prop = true; // get ready to read a propery value next!
     else if (prop && name) { o[name] = readValue(v); name = ''; prop = false; } // have name and in prop mode, set value and reset
     else name = v; // this can only be a property name, as all other conditions were handled
  });
  return root;
}
```

Usage: `parse(s);` where `s` is your string, of course. ;)

Note that this only creates arrays when names duplicate.  You can easily change it to always create an array at each nested level.